# Only the WP CLI command, wp --info, runs under my cPanel account

Tags: wp-cli

Please review the following commands I have issued remotely to the Bash Shell on my dedicated cPanel/WHM server:

> [root@host ~]# wp cli update
> Success: WP-CLI is at the latest version.

Then I switched to a cPanel account (with shell access) that hosts a WordPress site:

> [root@host ~]# su -l chaseland
> Last login: Fri Oct 30 15:17:01 MDT 2020 on pts/0

…and the `--info` command does indeed work:

> [chaseland@host ~]$ wp --info
> OS:   Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun > 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64
> Shell:    /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell
> PHP binary:   /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php
> PHP version:  7.4.11
> php.ini used: /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/etc/php.ini
> WP-CLI root dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
> WP-CLI vendor dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
> WP_CLI phar path: /home/chaseland
> WP-CLI packages dir:
> WP-CLI global config:
> WP-CLI project config:
> WP-CLI version:   2.4.0

However, any other command I try to execute produces an error:

> [chaseland@host ~]$ wp plugin update --all
> Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
> Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.
> [chaseland@host ~]$

This is my first installation of WP CLI and am having difficulty determining what to do next.

Thank you for any assistance,
Don

Comment: So from what folder exactly did you execute the commands? You need to execute them from within a Wordpress installation. Otherwise specify its location with `--path`. Anything special to you WordPress installation?

Comment: You need to find the folder with wp-config.php in it. Where this is will depend on how your host is set up: it may be in a public_html file in your home directory if this is a shared-hosting setup, or it might be under /var/www/html or similar if you have your own VM or VPC, or even /usr/share/wordpress on some systems.

Comment: If you're not sure where to look I'd ask your host. Alternatively if you can probably find a reference to the path in your webserver configuration which is probably under /etc/httpd or /etc/nginx.

Comment: I don't see how to post a reply, so I simply added a comment. The command was issued from the home directory where the wp-config.php file is located, which is how I set up all my WP installations. This is a dedicated server with CentOS 7 as the operating system. I am the host.

Comment: Hi... this is Don again. I was under the impression I could install WP CLI as the root user and use it on all cPanel accounts on my dedicated device by using the switch user (su) command before executing WP CLI commands. The reason I had this idea is due to the fact wp-cli is offered as an RPM in my WHM control panel; however, now I'm wondering if I need to install wp-cli under each cPanel account hosting WordPress. Thanks, Don